# Rendering an aurelia custom element in ag-grid header

Tags: aurelia, ag-grid

Is there an "easy" way to render a custom element in ag-grid header cell?  The headercomponent interface seems like an overly cumbersome approach to a seemingly simple problem and I have not been successful with this approach.  The closest I have come is to use something like:

`header-cell-render.bind="myHeaderRenderer"`

which is currently a function returning a string of HTML.  While this "works" (though I understand it is deprecated), in the sense that the html is injected into the DOM, only primitive HTML renders.  Meaning I can return something like:

`<input type="checkbox" />`

and it will render a checkbox, but I cannot return something like:

`<my-custom-element></my-custom-element>`

I can see that markup in the DOM, but the element doesn't "process", that is the Aurelia aspect of the control is not executed.

I am using the latest versions of ag-grid, ag-grid-aurelia.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you importing your custom element component like this `<require from="../templates/myCustomElement"></require>`

Comment: @adiga The element I am trying to use is registered as a global resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible out of the box with ag-grid-aurelia.

This is because ag-grid-aurelia [makes no special handling](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-aurelia/blob/master/src/agGridColumn.ts#L8) for this binding. The proper way to handle this is using [replaceable parts](http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-template-parts/) which allows you to specify a template for Aurelia to inject and consume. ag-grid makes this a bit harder since it seems the only native tool for injecting content into the header is [by passing an HTML string or an HTML element in the column configuration](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#gsc.tab=0). This can likely be added to the ag-grid-aurelia library by using a combination of replaceable parts and the `@children` decorator to gain access to the aurelia-rendered header element and pass it to the column configuration.